# Is it possible to have cells(c, 8).value inside datevalue command in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA. Hope someone can help.
Currently, cells(2,8) = 31-Dec-14 and I want to have 31-Dec-15 in cells(2,3). This is to be done until last record x.

What I have now:

```
Dim x As Long
x = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
For c = 2 To x
If Cells(c, 11).Value = "Success" Then
    Cells(c, 3).Value = Cells(c, 8).Value
End If
Next c
```

I want to replace Cells(c,8).Value with something that will show the same result with function,

```
=Text(Date(Year(H2)+1,Month(H2)+1,0),"dd-mmm-yy")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula in VBA:

```
Format(DateSerial(Year(Cells(c, 8).Value), Month(Cells(c, 8).Value) + 1, 0), "dd-mmm-yy")
```

We use `Format()` in the place of `TEXT()` and `DateSerial()` in place of `DATE()`

so:

```
Dim x As Long
x = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
For c = 2 To x
If Cells(c, 11).Value = "Success" Then
    Cells(c, 3).Value = Format(DateSerial(Year(Cells(c, 8).Value), Month(Cells(c, 8).Value) + 1, 0), "dd-mmm-yy")
End If
Next c
```

Though the above will return a string in the form of a date and not a true date.  If you want a date that can be used in other formulas you would want to use a NumberFormat on the receiving cell.

```
Dim x As Long
x = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
For c = 2 To x
If Cells(c, 11).Value = "Success" Then
    Cells(c, 3).Value = DateSerial(Year(Cells(c, 8).Value), Month(Cells(c, 8).Value) + 1, 0)
    Cells(c, 3).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
End If
Next c
```

This will return the correct format and keep the date as a number that can be used in future formulas.